# using java variable from another file method in run of other file

Tags: java, arrays, variables, static, static-methods

I have two files like this:

Client.java:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
//code

   public void run() {
   //more code
       Crypt cls = new Crypt();
       cls.decrypt(request,key,type);
       //print "val" here.
   //more code
   }
}
```

And then the Crypt.java file which is like this:

```
public class Crypt{

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] val, byte[] key, int type)
    {

        //val assigned here
        // the following is used to assign it.
       val[length - len - 1] ^= key[8 + (((byte)(key[8 + b] + key[8 + a])) & 0xFF)];


      return val;
    }   

}
```

I need to be able to access the val variable in in the Client.java file again after it has run through the Crypt.java file.

I've tried `cls.val` and `cls.decrypt.val` but I don't know how to get it working.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: where did you declare `val`? It is a method local variable or instance variable or static variable?

Comment: Store the return value `byte[] res = cls.decrypt(request,key,type);`

Comment: Just assign the result of  `cls.decrypt()` to something. Also, it seems that it's the original byte array that was passed to the method. So your `request` variable is also pointing to it.

Comment: @tomse post as answer m8 ;)

Comment: You don't have to use the new operator even - `Crypt cls = new Crypt()`, because `decrypt()` is a static method. See my answer.

Comment: Cool, I'll accept it in a min

Comment: (... posted as answer now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dycrypt()` method in class `Crypt` is a `static` member of the `Crypt` class. So you don't need to create an instance of `Crypt` class in `Client` class like -

```
Crypt cls = new Crypt();
cls.decrypt(request,key,type);
```

You can just call the `decrypt()` method using the class name and store the returns into a `byte[]` array -

```
byte[] vals = Crypt.decrypt(request, key, type);
```

Then using a for loop/for-each loop you can print the `vals` array -

```
for(byte each : vals){
   System.out.println(each);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `decrypt()` method returns a value, assign it to a variable when you call it.

`byte[] result = cls.decrypt(request, key, type);`

and then your `result` variable is the value you want, in `Client.java` and ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the return value of `dectypt` to a variable and use it.

```
byte[] res = cls.decrypt(request,key,type);
```